# Why does CVE-2019-2130 show up in Ubuntu and NodeJS?

Tags: android, cve, node.js

In the [NVD report](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-2130) for CVE-2019-2130 it shows that the products that are affected are only Android, and the links found in the [Mitre page of the CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-2130) lead only to an [Android report](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2019-08-01) of the CVE.

This is fine, yet what confused me is why the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker page](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2019/CVE-2019-2130.html) shows this vulnerability is also found in NodeJS and Chromium Browser.

So, my question is this:

Why is the CVE also found in NodeJS and Chromium when the NVD page only shows information about the vulnerability in Android? Is this a false positive?